# Balance sheet using SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a table-  Transactions as below-
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BhGk5.jpg

We need to have a column 'Balance' which will show the balance of each customer after they have a credit/debit in their account.

Example 1- Considering the initial balance for a customer A1 as 0, if there is 'Credit' of 300, the Balance column should say 300.
If there is 'Debit' of 100 after that, it should show 200 i.e 300-100.

Example 2- Considering the initial balance for a customer B1 as 0, if there is 'Debit' of 300, the Balance column should say -300
If there is 'Credit' of 100 after that, it should say -200 i.e -300+100

I'm uncertain how this can be achieved. Please assist.

Below are the scripts for sample data-

````sql
    create table transactions (transaction_id number, customer_id varchar2(5), transaction_type varchar2(15), amount number);

    insert into transactions values(1,'A1', 'Credit',100)
    insert into transactions values(2,'A3', 'Credit',2000);
    insert into transactions values(3,'B1', 'Debit',300);
    insert into transactions values(4,'A1', 'Debit',1900);
    insert into transactions values(5,'A3', 'Debit',1200);
    insert into transactions values(6,'B1', 'Credit',1400);
    insert into transactions values(7,'C1', 'Credit',30000);
    insert into transactions values(8,'B1', 'Debit',2000);
    insert into transactions values(9,'A3', 'Credit',4000);
    insert into transactions values(10,'A1', 'Debit',200);
    insert into transactions values(11,'C1', 'Credit',300);

    select * from transactions;```
````

Comment: It sounds like you are after a running windowed sum.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the analytic function `sum()` :

```sql
select t.*,
       sum(case when transaction_type = 'Credit' then amount else -amount end)
           over (partition by customer_id order by transaction_id) as balance
from transactions t
```